# Entity framework 4 + WCF + Silverlight Model associations problem

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a problem sending my entity objects through a WCF service to a Silverlight application.
I have a Vehicle class and it works fine until I assign a many to many relationship to a Session class in my entity model.
On the service side, I successfully retrieve my vehicles, but when when handling the response in the Silverlight app, I get the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: Not Found

I tryed to change the lazy loading options but it didn't change anything...any idea?

**EDIT**

I join the stacktrace of the exception and a picture of my entity model

```
   à System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   à SFVehicleManagement.VehicleServiceReference.VehiclesManagementServiceClient.VehiclesManagementServiceClientChannel.EndGetAllVehicles(IAsyncResult result)
   à SFVehicleManagement.VehicleServiceReference.VehiclesManagementServiceClient.SFVehicleManagement.VehicleServiceReference.VehiclesManagementService.EndGetAllVehicles(IAsyncResult result)
   à SFVehicleManagement.VehicleServiceReference.VehiclesManagementServiceClient.OnEndGetAllVehicles(IAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

[image: Entity model]

**EDIT2**

I should add, I created a brand new project with only 2 classes having a many-to-many association and a very simple service and silverlight app and get the same error

Comment: This could be a circular reference issue. Look around for WCF, EF integration issues with circular reference

Comment: Can you get the exception that is being thrown? Be sure to enable Silverlight debugging. Chandermani is probably on the right track but it will be easier for us to help with the full stacktrace.

Comment: I tried to modify my entity model as I think you're right, I had circular references. I Join it to my question. But I still get the problem. The exception is in the reference proxy channel. I join the stack too, but it's not explicit

Comment: Is it a good workaround to make my own POCO to use with services rather than just send entities objects?